# Event WhoID is null in lightning?

Tags: event, null

i created a trigger (EventBeforeInsert) that use the WhoID of the event to do other things, it works perfectly in the classic but in lightning this particular field is  null in my code although the contact is attached to the event in the lightning UI (thus, WhoID should not be null), i tried to figure out if there is another field specifically used in lightning  instead of WhoID  but i found nothing, do you have an idea ?
here is a screen shot to an event just before being created (you can see the contact attach to the event):

[image]

My trigger code is just a call to another method:

```
trigger EventBeforeInsert on Event (before insert) {

    System.debug('########### trigger BEGIN: EventBeforeInsert#####################');
         System.debug(trigger.new);
        AP05Event.EventReportFields(trigger.new);

    System.debug('########### trigger END: EventBeforeInsert#####################');  
}
```

Here is the developer console debug, the whoID is null:

[image]

Comment: How are you creating the Event in the Lightning UI? Can you give us a screen capture and also post the code for your trigger? Please read [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: Seeing the method would be helpful. Is this a custom event page we're looking at? I see that it's in a different language is why I'm asking. I see in your debug output the who count. Do you have "Allow Users to relate Multiple Contacts to Tasks & Events" enabled in Lightning? It's under Setup>Sales>ActivitySettings.

Comment: No it's the standard page, it's just french. For the method i can post it but as you can see in the trigger code, i added a system.debug() before calling the method just to test the content of the trigger.new list ans as you can see in the screen capture below the whoID is already null so , the method i am calling just after does not interfere in any way (that 's my opinion) . also the "Allow Users to relate Multiple Contacts to Tasks & Events" is enabled in my lightning environment. it's really weird this problem, it's driving me crazy

Comment: @crmprogdev can you please try it by creating a dummy trigger to verify if the problem is just in my environment or in lightning ?

Comment: i run some test in my personal test environment and i noticed that when "Allow Users to relate Multiple Contacts to Tasks & Events" is disabled in  lightning, it works, but once this is enabled it stops working and the value of WhoId becomes null

Answer (score 1):

Here's what's happening. Because you have "Allow Users to relate Multiple Contacts to Tasks & Events" enabled, you likely have `IsGroupEvent` set to `true` by default, in which case you need to be using `EventWhoIds` instead of the `WhoId` in your trigger.

Otherwise, you need to set `IsGroupEvent = false` in your dialogue so the contact will be used for the `WhoId` instead of being added to the string of `EventWhoIds`.

Comment: I will try it right now and keep you updated

Comment: I meant to add this link from the the [Object Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_event.htm).

Comment: great answer and would apply to Classic as well

Comment: @crmprogdev unfortunately the IsGroupEvent is already equal to false and the EventWhoIds returns an empty list. thank you any way for the answer.

Comment: If that's what's happening, I recommend you file a case with Salesforce. This sounds like a bug to me.

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same problem.
Event.whoid field was not accessible in before Event Trigger.

I have opened a case to Salesforce support, which they marked as a bug. [Known Issue page](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?title=whoid-is-null-in-before-insert-trigger-on-event-object-when-triggered-through-lightning&Id=a1p3A000000mCob).

while waiting the fix, there are 2 workarounds:

- Disable "Shared Activities should result in the WhoId being populated.
- If "Allow Users to Relate Multiple Contacts to Tasks and Events" is disabled, you will get the WhoID no matter the trigger run under "before insert" or "after insert".

  - If "Allow Users to Relate Multiple Contacts to Tasks and Events" is enabled, you will get the WhoID only under "after insert", not under "before insert. "